# PHP If not between numbers 1-6

Tags: php

I wanted to know the best way to check if the numbers are not between 1-6 without having to make a line of code for each number.

So, if number not between 1-6 then echo "wrong number"

Comment: It's a very basic question and smells like homework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if ($number < 1 || $number > 6) {
    echo "wrong number";
}
```

To answer the question in your comment, here is how you can check to also make sure it's not a letter.

```
if (!is_numeric($number) || ($number < 1 || $number > 6)) {
    echo "wrong number";
}
```

Comment: `if number not between 1-6 then echo "wrong number"` - the first paragraph was admittedly ambiguous but the second seemed pretty clear, so I fixed it for you :-)

Comment: Thanks! Now say a letter was entered, how could you stop that too?

Comment: Add is_numeric($number) to the if statement.

Comment: @Sam, this isn't a conversation. You're supposed to provide _all_ required information up front. What you have there is _another_ question which shold be in, well, another question :-)

Comment: @Nick, when I changed the sense of the comparison, I forgot to switch it from AND to OR, so I've fixed that as well. Sorry.

Comment: if (!is_numeric($steal) || ($steal < 1 && $steal > 6)) {
    echo "wrong number2";
}

That only seems to work for if a letter has been entered. Doesn't work for numbers that are not between 1-6

Comment: Did you have to add `my own example to your answer` .. is that now called duplication and copying @Nick Clark

Comment: That's better. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @Baba, if you could see the history, you'd notice that the code was changed to what you have (other than me accidentally forgetting to change and/or) two minutes before your answer was even posted. It was also done by me rather than Nick. Short of some temporal disturbance in the space-time continuum, I'm not certain a plagiarism claim will hold up :-) And, to be brutally honest, there's only a few ways you could _write_ that `if` statement.

Comment: few way for `if` .. i don't agree .. `PHP If not between numbers 1-6` can be written over 20 ways ..  but i quite agree it might be coincidence .. quick question since you have 3yes experience here .. what is the time lag (cache) for other people answer to appear .. i notice that i suddenly see so many reply only after i have posted and some are even like 3mins before mine .. thanks @paxdiablo